# SharePoint 2013- Intranet site search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

i was created a intranet site with publishing template. My site contains sub sites and pages also.

I created a publishing page with search result web part for search functionality . But When i try to search page title, unable to find any results in search results.

I don't have any knowledge on search functionality. Please provide clear steps to create search page in share point 2013.

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there either a small issue about setting up you Search page, try searching YouTube for Peter Kalmstrom as his videos are short and on the target. If that does not solve your issue then your basic Search setup might be missing and then this is an excellent source https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/10/29/set-up-a-search-center-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

does the search web part include reference document type or an enterprise category list to select from? Sounds like you cannot find your docs in search because they aren't tagged or properly spidered. Look for a bar that allows you to add meta tags to your documents so they appear in searches. If you're pushing it up to the main page from a subsite, it will take appx. 4 hrs

Answer (score 0):

Have you run a crawl before you search the page?

Go to Central Administration > Search Service Application > Crawl Log > URL View and check if you can search for this page.

For creating a new search result page, you can follow below steps:

1. Create a new page.
2. Add a Search Results Web Part.
3. Open the WebPart Properties and click on “Change Query”: This will open another dialogue
4. Make sure that the default value of the query is {searchboxquery}

To make the new page available via a new tab below the Searchbox execute the following configuration steps:

1. Go to the “Site Settings”:

Within the section “Search” of the Site Settings page click on "Search Settings".

2. In the section “Configure Search Navigation” add another Link for your new search results page and click on "OK" to save your changes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. When i click on Crawl log get exception.                                      "Sorry, something went wrong 
Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY"

Comment: Maybe there are some other issue in your farm. For this error message, check if this article is useful: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dau-blog/2012/04/20/how-to-solve-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationclass-to-interface-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-_application/